# Passing URL Django Pattern in Datatables Column

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, django, datatables

I'm trying to pass a url into the "Guest Name", where the user clicks on the user and a modal will pop up that displays a form that you can input/view information related to that particular guest.  I've tried fooling around with the render function, but haven't had much success.  If I were to be doing this purely in Django, I would want the equivalent of {% 'namespace:guest_data_form' guest.pk %}, which would call a view to render the form within a modal.  How would I accomplish the same within datatables?

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" class="init">
     $(document).ready(function() {
         $('#example').DataTable( {
             autoWidth: true,
             ajax: {
                 url: "{% url 'guest_data_api' guest.id %}"
             },
             columns: [
                 { "data" : "Room Number" },
                 { "data" : "Occupancy" },
                 { "data" : "Guest Name" },
                 { "data" : "Check In" },
                 { "data" : "Check Out" }
             ],
             "columnDefs": [
                 { "width": "15%", "targets": 2 }
             ]
         } );
     } );
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Datatables allows you to define a function for the value of "data". So you can replace `{"data" : "Guest Name"}` with:

```
"data": function (row) {
    var $a = $('<a></a>').attr('href', row.guest_name.link).text(row.guest_name.text);
    return $a.prop('outerHTML');
}
```

This assumes you are replacing the guest_name column with a json object that has a link/text attribute. You could also just pass the link as an escaped javascript string if you know it's safe wish to keep your datatables/js side simpler.

See more here: https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.data